# How to fillna (impute) by using the mean of the last 3 rows in the same column?

Tags: python, pandas

so I was trying to impute some missing values with fillna() in pandas, but I don't really know how to impute by using the mean value of the last 3 rows in the same column (not the mean value of the entire column), so if anyone can help it will be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with sample data and your expected output. You should be able to get an answer pretty quickly if you do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `fillna` with `rolling(3).mean()`. `shift` gets the alignment correct. This approach fills everything at once, so for consecutive `NaN` values the fillings are independent. If you need iterative filling (fills the first `NaN` then that value is used to compute the fill value in the next consecutive `NaN`) then it cannot be done in this way.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [np.NaN, 3, 4, 5, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, 7]})

                        # Fill if 
                        # at least 
                        # one value
df.fillna(df.rolling(3, min_periods=1).mean().shift())  # works for many cols at once
```

---

```
   col1
0   NaN  # Unfilled because < min_periods
1   3.0
2   4.0
3   5.0
4   4.0  # np.nanmean([3, 4, 5])
5   4.5  # np.nanmean([np.NaN, 4, 5])
6   5.0  # np.nanmean([np.NaN, np.naN ,5])
7   7.0
```

Comment: thank you very much for the solution mate! one more question though, what if I wanted to do iterative filling? how can i implement the solution for this? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
df.fillna(df.iloc[-3:].mean())
```

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'var1':[1, 2, 3, np.nan, 5, 6, 7],
                   'var2':[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1, 0]})

   var1  var2
0   1.0   NaN
1   2.0   NaN
2   3.0   NaN
3   NaN   NaN
4   5.0   NaN
5   6.0   1.0
6   7.0   0.0

print(df.fillna(df.iloc[-3:].mean()))
```

Output:

```
   var1  var2
0   1.0   0.5
1   2.0   0.5
2   3.0   0.5
3   6.0   0.5
4   5.0   0.5
5   6.0   1.0
6   7.0   0.0
```

Comment: Your output isn't returning the mean. Row 4, should have var1 = 2.0 as this is the mean of the previous three rows. I've written a loop that works, but your solution is much simpler and prettier.

Comment: OP wants the means of the last 3 rows in the columns, in my example that is the mean of [5, 6, 7] which is 6, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Well, he does say that, but I thought he meant the last three rows previous to the nan. I'm probably reading into it too much.

Comment: @Nicko ah I think you might be right... I'll wait for OP to clarify and delete my answer if so!

Answer (score 0):

Dan's solution is much simpler if the kink is worked out. If not, this will accomplish it:

```
df2 = df1.fillna('nan')  # Just filling them for the loop
dfrows = df2.shape[0]
dfcols = df2.shape[1]
for row in range(dfrows):
    for col in range(dfcols):
        if df2.iloc[row, col] == ('nan'):
            df2.iloc[row,col] = (df2.iloc[row-1,col] + df2.iloc[row-2,col] + df2.iloc[row-3,col])/3
df2
```